# Property 'toString' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: angular, typescript

[If i run this file its working fine . but when i wanted to make this file into ng build --prod it Redirect me to please remove this before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7brJB.png)

Comment: `value` is typed `[]` which is an empty array so there is never something inside type wise hence the inferred type `never`. Try to type `value` correctly or at least, have something like `value: any[]` which wouldn't break typescript (but wouldn't be type safe either though)

Comment: You need to specify the type of value. If you replace your  ` value: [] `  for the ```value: string[]```

Comment: Your "value" and "key" parameters are of type never change them to the correct type or to any[] (like the "list" param).  The never type is used when you are sure that something is never going to occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'as string' to tell the program to consider the variable 'name' as a string.

```js
value.forEach((name as string, index) => {...})
```